# WooCommerce Payment Method doesn't show in Checkout Payment Block

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, gutenberg-blocks, payment-method

I recently created a plugin for customized payment platforms on WooCommerce, it seems to work in the back-end and I can activate this custom payment gateway from the settings, but it doesn't seem to show in WooCommerce checkout page *(I am using Checkout Blocks)*.

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Plugin for Woocommerce Subscriptions + Xendit
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Author Name: Emmanuel John Navarro
 * Description: Plugin integration to create subscription based payments with automated integration to Xendit
 * Version 0.1.0
 * 
 * 
 */



add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_xen_payment_init',00);

function woocommerce_xen_payment_init(){
    if(class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')){
        #[AllowDynamicProperties]
        class WC_xen_payment extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
            public function __construct() {
                $this->id = 'xen_payment';
                $this->icon = apply_filters('woocommerce_payment_icon', plugins_url() . '/assets/icon.png');
                $this->has_fields = false;
                $this->method_title = __('Credit Cards/E-Wallets','xen-pay-woo');
                $this->method_description = __('Pay Through Credit Cards or E-Wallets Through XENDIT, Personal Information will NOT be stored','xen-pay-woo');
            $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            
            $this->instructions =  $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );
            
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();
        }
        public function init_form_fields(){
            $this->form_fields = apply_filters('xen_pay_fields',array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title' => __('Enable/Disable','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'type' =>'checkbox',
                    'label'=> __('Enable or Disable Payments','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'default'=>'no'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title' => __('Payment Gateway Name','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'type' =>'text',
                    'default'=>__('Credit Cards/E-Wallets','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'desc_tip'=> true,
                    'description'=> __('Add a new title for the payment gateway that customers will see in the checkout page','xen-pay-woo')
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title' => __('Payment Gateway Description','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'type' =>'textarea',
                    'default'=>__('This gateway accepts VISA, MASTERCARD, ETC','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'desc_tip'=> true,
                    'description'=> __('Add a new description for the payment gateway that customers will see in the checkout page','xen-pay-woo')
                ),
                'instructions' => array(
                    'title' => __('Instructions','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'type' =>'textarea',
                    'default'=>__('Kindly check your account page and reload to contact your personal graphics manager. Thank you so much for choosing HelloGFX','xen-pay-woo'),
                    'desc_tip'=> true,
                    'description'=> __('Place a product description that will be shown after checkout on EMAIL and THANK YOU PAGE','xen-pay-woo')
                )
                
            ));
        }

        public function process_payment($order_id){
            $order_id = wc_get_order($order_id);

            $this->clear_payment_with_api();

            $order->update_status('pending-payment',  __('Awaiting Payments','xen-pay-woo'));

            $order->reduce_order_stock();
            
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            return array(
                'result'=>'success',
                'redirect'=>$this->get_return_url($order)
            );
        }
        public function clear_payment_with_api(){

        }
    }
}
}

add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways','add_to_woo_xen_payment');

function add_to_woo_xen_payment( $gateways ){
    $gateways[] = 'WC_xen_payment';
    return $gateways;
}
```

Kindly let me know if anyone has any idea why it won't show on the checkout page.

Comment: Your plugin works and it's loaded… When enabled from WooCommerce > Settings > Payment, it's added and displayed in checkout page payment options *(but there are still some mistakes in your code)*. So there is something that is making trouble, it can be your theme, an additional plugin or some other custom code you added.

Comment: Thanks for the message, was wondering if it had something to do with integration with blocks payment, but I can't seem to find out how to integrate it, for the plugins, I'm not really using any other plugins besides the one with the code above and woocommerce, kindly let me know if this helps in understanding the situation. Thanks

Comment: Would you know how to disable block checkouts ? I heard ever since a certain woocommerce update, they had block checkouts as the default, thanks !

Comment: Your custom payment gateway is not compatible with Checkout blocks… To change checkout from blocks to classic, in the backend, go to Pages and edit checkout page *(keep your custom payment method active)*: Select the "payment options" block… Then on right column, you will see a warning box saying *"Some active extensions do not yet support this block... "* and with a button *"Switch to classic checkout"*… Click on *"Switch to classic checkout"* and continue the process until you get the classic checkout...

Comment: For checkout blocks custom payment gateways, see these links: https://medium.com/@hizanaoa40463/crafting-a-custom-woocommerce-payment-gateway-with-checkout-blocks-support-dfa6046eb48b | 
https://sevengits.com/payments-with-woocommerce-checkout-blocks/ | 
https://developer.woo.com/2021/03/15/integrating-your-payment-method-with-cart-and-checkout-blocks/ | 
The search URL for checkout blocks custom payment gateway: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=woocommerce+custom+payment+gateway+for+blocks&atb=v404-1&ia=web

Comment: Thanks Loic ! this helped out a lot, would you know the differences of the block and classic payments, this would be in the context of me coding the template from scratch. Thanks again

Comment: **Classic Checkout** use WooCommerce classic templates and related template hooks… **Blocks  Checkout** don't use WooCommerce classic templates and related template hooks and are much more complicated to customize, but offer from settings more options and a cleaner new styling…